# Can I commit a shortcut to subversion (and get it back in a usable form)

Tags: windows, svn, shortcut, windows-shortcut

What happens if I commit a Windows shortcut to subversion?

([Motivation here](https://superuser.com/questions/100249/how-to-pin-either-a-shortcut-or-a-batch-file-to-the-new-windows-7-taskbar), though I don't honestly expect to actually do it, but I have [done something similar in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056092/what-happens-if-i-add-a-symbolic-link-to-subversion) in the past.)

Suppose I add and commit a shortcut to subversion in Win7:

- Can I use it if I check it out again later?
- Will my teammates be able to use it, when they check it out to the same path?
- Can I create a shortcut that uses a relative path?
- Does it matter that I use SlikSvn and the rest tend to use TortoiseSVN?
- Can I check it out to Windows Server 2012 or some other version of windows and expect it to work?

TIA.